# Adding blur effect to CSS loader

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have integrated a loader feature such that when users click on the submit button, a loader is displayed on the page, indicating that the form submission is in progress. How can I apply a blur effect to the entire page while the loader is active, excluding the loader itself from blurring?

I have tried setting the body to blur, like this:

```
body.loading {
    filter: blur(5px);
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

But it completely hid the spinner causing the entire page to turn into a white background. Here is my code so far:

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById("postForm");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const loader = document.querySelector(".loading");
  loader.classList.add("visible");

  document.body.classList.add("loading");
  document.getElementById("submitbutton").disabled = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    event.target.submit()
  }, 1000);
})
```

````css
```
body.loading {
filter: blur(5px);
pointer-events: none; 
}

.loading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  visibility: none;
}

.loading::after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 10px solid #dddddd;
  border-top-color: #009579;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 1s linear infinite;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes loading {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```
````

````html
```
<button id="submitbutton" type="submit">Create
   <div class="loading"></div>
</button>

<form id="postForm"></form>
```
````

Comment: Please revise the demo above to show your problem. You could probably simplify. I doubt the script is relevant. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: You could use pseudo elements and sit them on top of the page - eg use the before for the blur and the after for the laoder and give the loader a higher z-index

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the loader to show while the blur is in place and loading is taking place, you could `position: absolute` the loader and give it a high z-index.

That way, the loader will show above other elements, while everything else will be behind blur.

You can also try having a separate 'blur' div that is also position absolute but fills the screen when loading takes place. That way existing content on the screen is unaffected, but you have a translucent div overlapping it all.

Comment: @hendel ekstein any success?